# Can you read from multiple columns using a single foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm creating a script to read from a imported csv file. There are two columns titled 'userID' and 'domain' respectively, which are used to create an email address based on the domain listed ("texas", "orlando",etc).

I currently have this to iterate through the IDs manually placed, but would also like to grab the values from the second column and work with them.

```
forEach ($E in $ws.'userID') {

"do something"

}
```

Have this to start with but I don't think it will work how I want it to

```
forEach ($E in $ws.'userID', $D in $ws.'domain') {

"do something"

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, assuming `$ws` is an array or list of objects that each have `userID` and `domain` properties:

```
foreach($e in $ws){
  # do something with $e.userID
  # do something with $e.domain
}
```